# How to run a shell script after a device is mounted using UDEV

Tags: mount, udev, automount

I wanted to know how to run a script after a usb pen drive is inserted and auto-mounted
Till know i am able to run a script as soon as the device is inserted, however the mounting of the device takes place after the shell script action has ended

Answer (score 2):

You can write udev rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` and use the `RUN` like :

```
KERNEL=="sd?1",ATTRS{serial}=="001CC27F",ACTION=="add",RUN+="/path/to/script.sh'"
```

note : script.sh will be run with root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to listen for the appropriate D-Bus signals notifying that the volume has been mounted.